# file(1) command termination when using the -f - option

Tags: command-line, files, stdin

Say I'd like to use the `file -f -` command inside a script, and send some input using the stdin, when I'm finished I'd like to terminate it gracefully, but unfortunately I haven't found any way to do this (and yes I did read the man page :) ).

Comment: `ls|file -f -` works fine for me. How do you "send some input"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to send `EOF` signal when you finished. To do that, you need to press `CTRL + D`:

```
$ file -f -
test.py
test.py:       a /usr/bin/python script, ASCII text executable
test.pl  
test.pl:       a /usr/bin/perl script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
<CTRL + D here>
```

or you can send to file inside shell script via `HERE DOC`:

```
file -f - <<EOF
test.pl
test.py
test.awk
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Method #1 - Using a heredoc

A [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) as [@Gnouc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119938/7453) shows in his answer is an easy way to accomplish what you want if you have a random list of files to pass to `file`.

#### Method #2 - Using find

If you're needing to do this on a directories worth of files you can use `find` and have it call `file` for the entire set of files in the results.

*Example*

```
$ find . -exec file {} +
.:       directory
./adir:  directory
./afile: empty
```

The `find` command can then be used to select the appropriate set of file and/or directories either by type or by their names' using patterns via `find`.

#### Method #3 - Using a for loop

If it's just a set of files in the current directory then a for loop can also accomplish the task.

*Example*

```
$ for i in *;do file $i;done
adir: directory
afile: empty
```

Again you can use regular expressions to help filter the results as needed.